How to redirect expo router to a folder in app load (for logged in users)
In my React Native app I use Expo routing and with the global session management, I have the below _layout.tsx file which simply checks if the user is logged in, then redirect to other folders if not, redirects to the login screen.
Hierarchy:
app/
    auth/
          _layout.tsx            
          login.tsx              
         business_auth/
            index.tsx           
            _layout.tsx         
         staff_auth/
            index.tsx
            _layout.tsx
         registration/
            index.tsx
            business_reg.tsx
            staff_reg.tsx
            _layout.tsx
    _layout.tsx
    +html.tsx
    +not-found.tsx

However, with the current setup, if the user is logged in it automatically loads up the first folder in the folder which is (buiness_auth). However, depending on the role of the logged in user, I want to have some logic to decide which folder it can have access to.
For example if the logged in user has it's role set as 'staff' then it should redirect to (staff_auth).
I have the below code but it always redirect to business folder when I open the app since alphabetically it is correct.
Just to be clear, I can redirect correctly after login. But the problem is when you open the app with an existing session.
auth/_layout.tsx
import * as SplashScreen from "expo-splash-screen";
import { SessionProvider } from "@/services/ctx";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "login",
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}
import { Slot } from "expo-router";

function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      <Slot />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}

